# What is Nagilum’s true form?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, shape-shifter

[Nagilum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nagilum) expresses some surprise that the Enterprise-D members are shocked to see him in a “humanoid” form ([“Where Silence Has Lease”](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_(episode))). After all, it’s gone to such trouble to look like them!

Is there anything anywhere which mentions Nagilum’s “true” form?

Comment: According to the Memory Alpha... He has no true form.

Comment: Don't you mean "it?" :)

Comment: It says "he" in the question...

Comment: I'm going to change it. I think "it" is more appropriate for belngs like Nagilum, the Edo god, The Guardian of Forever, etc.

Comment: @Mithrandir - I'm struggling to see what Memory Alpha have based that assertion on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**We don't know.** It's described as an...

> "*....extra-dimensional lifeform*"

...by the [Star Trek Encyclopedia (3rd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671536095) and

> "*A powerful being, extra-dimensional in nature and **manifested in space
>   by a large hole of complete blackness***"

by the [StarTrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/nagilum-aliens) website.

---

That's pretty much all we've got to go on. That being said, (and given that it has no understanding of the concept of a "[limited existence](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/128.txt)" until it encounters the Enterprise) I think we can be reasonably sure that it doesn't have *any* sort of three-dimensional physical form, at least not one that we would understand.